# php sql doesnt recognise my variable and doesnt delete from data base

Tags: php, mysql, variables, drop-down-menu, global-variables

I am having trouble with my php file and my sql statement. I want to delete the user I have selected from a drop list. I have tried everything and doesnt delete from the db. please help me

main.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>    
 <?php
   $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     mysql_select_db("pruebas", $link);

     /* El query valida si el usuario ingresado existe en la base de datos. Se utiliza la función 
     htmlentities para evitar inyecciones SQL. */
     $myusuario = mysql_query("select nombre from usuarios");
     $nmyusuario = mysql_num_rows($myusuario);


//Como ya se dijo anteriormente la variable $conexion esta definida 
//en el archivo 'conexion_mysqli.php'

?>

<form method="post" name="lista_form" action="delete.php">

<select name="lista">    
    <?php    
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($myusuario) )    
    {
        ?>

        <option value=" <?php echo $row['nombre'] ?> " >
        <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>
        </option>

        <?php
    }    
    ?>        
</select>
<input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>


</body>

</html>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
     /* A continuación, realizamos la conexión con nuestra base de datos en MySQL */
     echo $_POST["lista"];
     $my_post=mysql_escape_string($_POST["lista"]);
     echo $my_post;
     $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     mysql_select_db("pruebas", $link);

     /* El query valida si el usuario ingresado existe en la base de datos. Se utiliza la función 
     htmlentities para evitar inyecciones SQL. */
 $sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = '$my_post'", $link);

if($sql !=  0)
   {
    echo 'You DELETE';


   }
else
   {
    echo 'Your not in';
   }
          ?>
```

Comment: The first step to troubleshooting might be splitting the SQL statement out and checking if it's correct. `$deleteStatement = "DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = '$my_post'"; echo $deleteStatement; $sql=mysql_query($deleteStatement, $link);`

Answer (score 0):

It would seem this is your problem:

```
<option value=" <?php echo $row['nombre'] ?> " >
               ^ here                       ^ and here
```

You are adding spaces around the string that comes from your database.

Apart from that you are not escaping your string for output to html so that could break your html and logic as well if the value contained a `"` character.

You should change it to something like:

```
<option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['nombre']); ?>" >
```

Also note that [`mysql_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) has been deprecated since php 4.3 (!) and all other `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated as well.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I have tried the 3 things you said and:

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I have tried the 3 things you said and: 1. works same without the spaces. 2. I replace the line as you mentioned and it deletes the drop down list, it doesnt give the option to select. 3. I deleted the mysql_escape_string and works the same, it doesnt make any difference. I realized that sql is no altering the table in the db, even when the sql is working.  thanx again for ur help

Comment: @PaolaA.MoralesPeña The function is `htmlspecialchars` without the `_`'s. And you should add `var_dump()`'s of your variables instead of using `echo` so that you see what it contains exactly.

Comment: I have tried without the _'s and now it shows the drop down list but it is still the same. it doesnt delete in the db. I got string(5) "pedro" when I use the var_dump()

Comment: Thanx jeroen, I have found also that the = doesnt work. I changed it for like and it work perfect.